# Why does this query suddenly return no results when adding more parameters in an IN clause?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I've got this mysql / mariadb query:

```
SELECT COUNT(0)  
FROM my_table
WHERE first_value IN (40908500, 40911700) 
AND second_value IN (21153400001) 
AND third_value IN ('49586')
```

The table is very straight forwards. first_value is an bigint key. second_value is also a bigint key. third_value is a varchar column.

This query returns 0, it did not find any occurances. Curiously, if I remove one of the values in brackets:

```
SELECT COUNT(0)  
FROM my_table
WHERE first_value IN (40911700) 
AND second_value IN (21153400001) 
AND third_value IN ('49586')
```

suddenly, I get the answer 1. This is the result I want. Curiously, this only happens to a small subset of queries, but I've seen it happen before. I don't see how adding more values in the "in" clause should suddenly invalidate other matches, especially since it works "most of the time" with the other values.

Comment: I've tried it with Count(1) as well, same result.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as it is not clear what you are doing do or trying to get here..

Comment: Trust me. I would LOVE to provide one. But I can't (without starting to export the database itself) because I can not reproduce the error consistently or even isolate out the errenous parts.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're misunderstanding the question. The second query does provide a result, because it finds a match. Even using Count(1), it finds a result. I could even go a step further and use SELECT * instead of count, and I would still find the result. Adding more parameters inside the IN clause, the brackets does an OR concatination, NOT an AND concatination. And because it's an OR concatination, it should STILL find the result.

Comment: Try to run query 1, then query 2, then query 1 again - maybe something happens to your data in between.

Comment: It would be good to include the version of the database you are using as this might be a bug.

Comment: @Adder the database is static. No data is changing after the initial import.

Comment: @markusjm MariaDB 10.4.6

Comment: Must be something else.. because it should work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7027a9f3ace17136c923f3e38936c24e

Comment: Yeah. But sadly I am at my wits end what exactly could be causing it.

Comment: What engine?  Are there any indexes?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Also `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each.